# How to add corresponding IDs from json file to dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

How do I add values from a json file to a dataframe, for the corresponding IDs? That is, in a dataframe I have 3000+ IDs, and in the json file I have 15000+ IDs with corresponding values, but I only want to add the values for the IDs that exist in the dataframe.

The json-file is on the format:
 {"1": ["X"], "2": ["Z"], "3": ["Y"], "4": ["X"]}

Comment: Put the json data into a DataFrame, throw away the IDs you don't need and add the rest to your existing DataFrame.

Comment: Do you know how I do that?

Answer (score 1):

you just read the json and after you transform to DataFrame:

```
import json
file = 'E:/test.json'   # {"1": ["X"], "2": ["Z"], "3": ["Y"], "4": ["X"]}
with open(file) as x_file:
    dict_x = json.load(x_file)

# converting json dataset from dictionary to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_x, orient='index').reset_index(level=0)
df.columns = ['ID', 'Letters']

print(df)
```

output:

```
  ID Letters
0  1       X
1  2       Z
2  3       Y
3  4       X
```

After its easy to add new columns...

Comment: When trying your solution, I get an error saying "TypeError: Expected list, got str". Do you have any ideas?

Comment: are you sure of the structure of your json? i have no error...print the result of dict_x after load file

Comment: Yeah then the format is {'ID1': ['label1'], 'ID2': ['label2'], 'ID3': ['label3'], etc...}

Comment: have you print and check if dict_x is dictionary?

Comment: Yes, I did print(dict_x) and then type(dict_x) which states that is a dict

Comment: the error is coming from  the creation of Dataframe? pd.DataFrame.from_dict

Comment: if you use my code with the same copy of json in the file test, have you error?